# How to define grid view inside RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following gridviews `gvAgreement` and nested grid-view `gvProducts`

I am looking for defining `gvProducts` inside `gvAgreement_RowCommand`

I have defined `gvProducts` in `gvAgreement_OnRowDataBound`

by the following code

```
protected void gvAgreement_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
    GridView gvProducts = e.Row.FindControl("gvProducts") as GridView;
}

protected void gvAgreement_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //your suggest code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you to find any child control inside parent gridview.

```
GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
Int32 rowIndex = gvRow.RowIndex; // required if you want to find index of the control from where event has been raised.  
GridView gvProducts = gvRow.FindControl("gvProducts") as GridView;
```